# How to replace wp-admin login page to another location?

Tags: php, wp-admin, login

```
// This will replace the login url

add_filter( 'login_url', 'custom_login_url', 10, 2 );

function custom_login_url( $login_url='http://www.example.com/login/', $redirect='http://www.example.com/login/' )
{

    // Set your $login_page_id

    return get_permalink(207);

}
```

Comment: flowing link can help you https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you dont want to add plugin

- First of all, To be safe than sorry take a backup of wp-login.php and store in a safe place just in case of any wrong step.

All you need is access to your site’s files and should have a text editor (I’m using VS Code). Now choose your ideal login UR, for example, /newlogin.php

Go to your public_html directory where you can find wp-login.php. You can open it

Once you find, Name this file whatever you want your login URL to be. In this case, I named it newlogin.php.

Next, open up the newlogin.php and find and replace every instance of "wp-login.php" in the file – then replace it with your new file name as newlogin.php

Now you should be able to log in by navigating to your new URL. In my case, it’s localhost/wp/newlogin.php. If any HTTP requests to the /wp-login.php, or /wp-admin directories will lead visitors to a 404 not-found page.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change url part of **'wp-admin'** with some other word like **myadmin** you can use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/